# Wht's the issue in following script in applying class to div based upon some condition in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to apply a specific class to a div based upon whether the checkbox contained inside div tag is disbaled or not. But I'm not able to apply or remove the class. Can you please help me out by guiding me how to achieve this? Following is my code:

```
<p id="parentCheckbox" class="custom-form"> 
  <input class="custom-check" type="checkbox" name="" id="ckbCheckAll">
</p>

<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox">
  <input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide ez-checked" type="checkbox" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      J2P: Electromagnetic Waves
  </label>
</p> 
<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox"><input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      NEET XII Testlet : Electrostatics 2
  </label>
</p>
<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox">
  <input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      J2P: Ray Optics & Optical Instruments
  </label>
</p>
<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox">
  <input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      NEET XII Testlet : Electrostatics 2
  </label>
</p>
<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox"><input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      J2P: Electromagnetic Waves
  </label>
</p>
<p class="custom-form">
  <div class="ez-checkbox"><input id="" class="custom-check checkBoxClass ez-hide" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" name="item[]"></input>
  </div>
  <label>
      NEET XII Test : Electrostatics
  </label>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  { 
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
    if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)'))
      $(".ez-checkbox input:not(:disabled)").removeClass("ez-checked");

    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(".ez-checkbox input:not(:disabled)").addClass("ez-checked");
  });
});
</script>
```

I've tried a lot to make the thing happen but couldn't. Please help me to make it happen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: share a fiddle link it would be much easier..

Comment: Make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select all checkboxes which are not disabled upon clicking the parent checkbox in following scenario?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218944/how-to-select-all-checkboxes-which-are-not-disabled-upon-clicking-the-parent-che)

Comment: @CBroe:I've written different logic for the question you are talking about than here. That ididn't work for me so i've changed the way to do things now.

Comment: I think some wrong in your question. Pls, check that. this fiddle for your question http://jsfiddle.net/9xLj8/ .

Comment: So instead of following up on one approach, to try and get a real understanding of the situation and the solution, you randomly switch to the next one.

Comment: @user2736012:I want to apply the ez-checked class to the all the div tags which doesn't contain disabled elements at the same time when I'm applying the class ez-checked to the checkbox which is not disabled. In short I wan to apply the class ez-checked to both the div container and the checkbox(which is not disabled) contained within it when the click event is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine, though it could be simplified.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYaPx/1/

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
    $(".ez-checkbox input:enabled").toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);
});
```

If it doesn't seem to work, either jQuery isn't loaded, or your `ez-checked` style isn't making a visual difference.

---

If you want to add the class to the `div`, then use `.parent()`, or `.closest()`.

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
    $(".ez-checkbox input:enabled").closest("div")
                                   .toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);
});
```

---

If you want to add the class to the `input` and the `div`, then combine the two solutions.

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () { 
    $(".ez-checkbox input:enabled").toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked)
                                   .closest("div")
                                   .toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: :Thanks for your help. I tried your trick now the ez-checked is getting applied to the checkbox which is not disabled. But along with this I've to apply the class ez-checked to all the div present which are not containing disabled checkboxes. Can you help me in achieving this?

Comment: @PHPGeek: I just updated to select the parent `div`. Are you saying you need to add the class to both the `input` and its `div`, or just the `div`?

Comment: :Thanks for your help. It worked perfectly. Now one small issue is stil there. After I checked parent checkbox all the child checkboxes and divs are getting the class ez-checked applied to them. But when I uncheck any of the child checkboxes then the parent checkbox is still checked i.e. the class ez-checked of parent is not getting removed and when I check all the child checkboxes one by one the parent should also get apply the class ez-checked automatically. That's not happening currently. Can you help me in correcting this issue?

Comment: @PHPGeek: Just add a handler to the individual checkboxes that does `$(this).toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked).closest("div").toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);`

Comment: :Can you please incorporate into your fiddle or answer given please? It would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To add/remove the class of the containing div, you just need to use the parent selector:

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LWNXd/

```
   // This follows the same logic as your current code,  just written slightly different
   $(document).ready(function()  { 
        $('#formA').on('click', '.ez-checkbox input:not(:disabled)',function(){
            var elem = $(this); 

            elem.parent('div')[ ((elem.is(':not(:checked)')) ? 'remove':'add')+'Class']('ez-checked');
        }); 
    });
```